# Echo inside __construct()

Tags: php, echo, construct

How to read variable inside __construct()?

Here's the sample code:

```
class Sample {
   private $test;

   public function __construct(){
      $this->test = "Some text here.";
   }
}

$sample = new Sample();
echo $sample->test;
```

What is wrong with this code? Because __construct is automatic, I just thought that it will run on class sample and read it automatically.

Is it possible to echo this out without touching __construct()?
Thank you.

Comment: I highly recommend you to read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make `$test` **public**. When it's private, it is only readable from within the class.

```
class Sample {
   public $test;

   public function __construct(){
      $this->test = "Some text here.";
   }
}

$sample = new Sample();
echo $sample->test;
```